# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is forbidden

Tags: php, mysqli

this is my first question, I've searched around and tried a few things. I'm probably missing somethings very obvious.
I'm using MAMP
PHP version: 7.4.9
Server version: 5.7.30 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Here is my SQL

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dsdb/OPENPO_01_ESP_20201118_090000.csv'
INTO TABLE tbl_StockOnOrderReport_test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

And here is the error

```
#2000 - LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is forbidden, check mysqli.allow_local_infile
```

I have tried a few things,

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv;
```

gives this

```
@@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv
NULL
```

I have Uncommented this line in PHP.ini

```
mysqli.allow_local_infile = On
```

Comment: "_I have Uncommented this line in PHP.ini_" Did you restart your webserver/PHP after making changes to php.ini?

Comment: I did restart, yes.

Comment: Tried without LOCAL ? So only LOAD DATA INFILE ..

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and I get,
#1290 - The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement
```SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";```gets ```secure_file_priv
NULL```

Comment: I do not have a my.ini file

Comment: I have now added the following to my.cnf
```
[mysqld_safe]
[mysqld]
secure_file_priv=""
```
All working now, many thanks.

Comment: So when would you use LOCAL ?